# How to invite users to connect to your application using Facebook Application Development interfaces

Tags: c#, javascript, facebook, invite

I think that this question already questioned, and probably the answer is here:
http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Notifications.send

but the real problem is that facebook says:
Facebook discontinued support for this method March 1, 2010. Calling this method returns error code 3 -- Unknown method.

while, I couldn't find any other JS-api for the invitation,
anyone know how we can invite users, using the JS api or the .net api?

thanks.

Answer (score 1):

> Application-to-user and user-to-user notifications have been removed. Instead you should use counters, news (in the dashboards), or send email (to users who have granted that permission), and check out our best practices for the new communication channels.

http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Roadmap_Notifications

Comment: this one is great, but not good enough.
the main problem that non of them is for inviting new users.
only for existing users.
this is the sentence in my wiki that I am looking for: 
"User A is an application user, and is friends with User B, who is not an application user."