# "Unknown Method" exception using FaceBook SDK to send notification

Tags: c#, facebook, sdk

I am using the Facebook C# SDK. For the following code it is throwing an exception saying "unknown method".

```
string to_id = "100001950403316";        
facebookService1.Notifications.Send(to_id, "my notification from samples ");
```

How can I rectify it?

Answer (score 1):

> Facebook discontinued support for this method from March 1, 2010

Read [How to invite users to connect to your application using Facebook Application Development interfaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2446912/how-to-invite-users-to-connect-to-your-application-using-facebook-application-de) and [How to use Facebook Application to write a notification to Users](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7614749/how-to-use-facebook-application-to-write-a-notification-to-users).